# query by timestamp range not working unless with keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

Newbie question on ElasticSearch:

I have following data with `http://localhost:9200/tutorial/_doc/7`:

```json
"_index":"tutorial","_type":"_doc","_id":"7","_version":3,"_seq_no":25,"_primary_term":2,"found":true,
"_source":{
  "message": "error",
  "@timestamp": "2022-05-16T09:40:00"
}
```

and I'm trying to find all records with `@timestamp` between `2022-05-16T09:30:00` and `2022-05-16T09:50:00` with following request:

```json
POST http://localhost:9200/tutorial/_search
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp.keyword": {
                  "gt": "2022-05-16T09:30:00",
                  "lte": "2022-05-16T09:50:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The question I have, is that why do I have to use `@timestamp.keyword` but not just `@timestamp` for the value under `range`? If I use the one without `keyword`, I'll get nothing back.

A bit context, I'm setting up Elastalert which requires a `@timestamp` field. I checked that the requests it sends to ElasticSearch put `@timestamp` as the range without `keyword`, therefore it's not giving me any value.

Result for `http://localhost:9200/tutorial` if it helps:

```json
{
   "tutorial":{
      "aliases":{
         
      },
      "mappings":{
         "properties":{
            "@timestamp":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               },
               "fielddata":true
            },
            "message":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings":{
         "index":{
            "routing":{
               "allocation":{
                  "include":{
                     "_tier_preference":"data_content"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_shards":"1",
            "provided_name":"tutorial",
            "creation_date":"1652405360958",
            "number_of_replicas":"1",
            "uuid":"OuynpaOiRyqQ1sj-b2xuYw",
            "version":{
               "created":"7170399"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@timestamp` field is not mapped correctly, as `text`/`keyword` field types are not appropriate for date values. You need to change your mapping to this instead:

```
        "@timestamp":{
           "type":"date"
        },
```

Then you'll be able to run your `range` query on `@timestamp`

Comment: thanks @Val I recreated the index and and yes it works properly if I have the type as `date`. Since I'm on it, wondering if there's a way to change the type from `text` to `date` without recreating the index? I tried `PUT http://localhost:9200/tutorial/_mapping` but got `mapper [@timestamp] cannot be changed from type [text] to [date]`